# Orient DB : suggestion query with weight

Tags: orientdb

In the blog post [Movielens Recommendation Engine with OrientDB](http://pizzaconnections.net/2015/03/27/148/), they write a query that finds movies rated 5 by user who also rated 5 to the movies rated 5 by #16:0.

Here is the model Person->(Rated)-> Movie

```
create class Movie extends V
create property Movie.title String
create class Person extends V
create property Person.id String
create class Rated extends E
create property Rated.rating int
```

Here is the original suggestion query

```
select title, count(*) as conto
  from (select expand(rid.outE('rated')[rating = 5].in)
          from (
        select @rid as rid, id as id, count(*) as conto
        from (select expand(outE('rated')    
              [rating=5].in.inE('rated'[rating=5].out) from #16:0)
              where @rid <> #16:0 group by rid, id order by conto desc limit 10))
 where title not in (select out('rated').title from #16:0)
 group by title
 order by conto desc
```

I was looking a way to add some weight : a user X who rated 5 to 100 of my movies would have more weight than a user Y who rated only 50 of my movies. 
Movie rated by X should be advantaged compared to Y.

This query can calculate the weight by returning the number of time other users rated 5 the movie rated 5 by #16:0 :

```
select @rid as rid, count(*) as p from (
      select from (
        select expand(outE('rated')[rating=5].in.inE('rated').out
                 ) from #16:0
      ) where @rid <> #16:0
    ) group by @rid order by p desc
```

But I don't know how to write the suggestion query to use this.

I try this, but it doesn't work

```
select @rid as rid, title, count(*) from (
  select expand(rid.outE('rated')[rating=5].in) from (
    select @rid as rid, count(*) as p from (
      select from (
        select expand(outE('rated')[rating=5].in.inE('rated').out
                 ) from #16:0
      ) where @rid <> #16:0
    )group by @rid order by p desc
  )
)
where @rid not in (select out('rated').@rid from #16:0) group by @rid
```

Comment: hi, do you have a test DB to share? Or maybe could you write out your schema details? Thanks

Comment: ok sorry, just saw the link at the beginning..

Comment: were you able to import the movie dataset with ETL? I'm stuck on that point, it doesn't recognize the custom *split* function in the import

Answer (score 0):

I found a query that can retrieve rated movies and their associate 'weight' :

```
select a.@rid as rid, weight from (
    select u.outE("rated")[rating=5].in as a, count(*) as weight from (
      select @rid as u from (
        select expand(outE('rated')[rating=5].in.inE('rated')[rating=5].out) from #13:0
      ) where @rid <> #13:0
    ) group by u
  ) 
unwind rid
```

I can now have the number of time, and the weight (I'm not sure some is a good idea)

```
select rid, count(*) as c, sum(weight) as w from(the_query_above)
where rid not in (select out("rated").@rid from #13:0)
group by rid
```

I m not sure it's the best way to do that, maybe someone have another idea ?